# Removing White Noise from ARIMA series

Tags: r, time-series, arima

I'm a student using R to analyze inflation rate data for school. I've obtained a time series of monthly inflation rates. Using R's *tseries* library, I found an ARMA(1,1) model fit to the time series. Both the ar1 and ma1 terms are significant at alpha < 0.001.

My question is given that the ARMA model is a linear combination of white noise, ar term, and ma term. Is there a way(using the ARMA fit) to obtain a series subtracting the white noise? I would like to see what the series looks like without white noise.

I hope this is a reasonable question and my understanding is correct. Doing this in R would be easiest.

[image: ARMA fit provided by R]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want the fitted values $\hat y_t$ which can be obtained using the function `fitted` from the `forecast` package as follows:

```r
fit <- arima(AirPassengers, order = c(0,1,1), seasonal = c(0,1,1));
library(forecast);
fitted(fit)
```

`fit` is the fitted model object on which you applie the `fitted` function. (I chose a certain model applied on the AirPassengers time series as an example; you will have to insert your own fitted model object there.) A similar question with an answer can be found on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033720/arima-fitted-values/50035237).